# Is it safe to treat 32-bit vectors stored in BitVector32, int and uint interchangably?

Tags: c#, .net, bitvector

After having implemented some logic with 32-bit bit vectors using `uint`, I found that there already exists a `BitVector32` inside [`System.Collections.Specialized`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.specialized(v=vs.110).aspx). The thing is, it uses `int` for its API and does casts to `uint` internally, along with some other checking in other cases.

Is there any case when one could run into issues combining these three options? Are are they completely interchangable apart from not having a subscript API on `int`/`uint`?

Comment: It would be super helpful to have the code to be able to provide an answer.

Comment: The three "options" you are referring to are `uint`, `int`, and `System.Collections.Specialized.BitVector32`, right? What issues are you thinking of? Of course "casts" (explicit conversions) between `int` and `uint` are more or less no-operations (at run-time) if you use `unchecked` context (which is the default). If you ever compile with `checked` context, that will break. But why would you? The type `BitVector32` is a struct whose only field is an `int`, I guess, and it should be unproblematic as well.

Comment: Casts between `int` and `uint` are effectively instructions to the *compiler* more than anything else. They essentially tell it to include the `.un` prefix on certain instructions (for arithmetic/comparison ops) where unsigned/signed make a difference. There's only two integer types so far as the VES is concerned (on the "execution" stack), and there the difference is 32/64 bit.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen In what case would it break in `checked`? I guess my question was mostly about when casts between `int` and `uint` do something other than change the type of the expression.

Comment: When the most significant bit is set, the conversion between `int` and `uint` will produce a run-time exception if you have compiled your program in `checked` context. For example `0x80000001u` is a `uint` interpreted as a positive number, 2 ** 31 plus 1. With unchecked, a cast to `int` will just leave the same value on the stack. But now it is interpreted as a negative number, minus 2 ** 31, plus 1. As Damien says, if you were to compare to the number `1` or `1u`, for example with `<` (less than), that would matter, of course. But in checked context, the conversion to `int` would just fail.